# How best to monitor and output live text data from a file in C# .net

Tags: c#, .net, text

Basically I've been tasked with compiling live text diagnostics files, concatenating and sorting them and outputting them to a single GUI. The output should make it clear which file each row came from.

here's some sample data:

```
14-Apr-11 15:10:27.691 CAL Report Terminate
14-Apr-11 15:25:18.723 DIAG_RESTART ******************* P r o c e s s   R e s t a r t e d  
14-Apr-11 15:25:18.733 IIF_II INITIALISING
14-Apr-11 15:25:18.733 IIF_II DISABLED
14-Apr-11 15:25:19.013 IIF_II ENABLED
```

every row starts with a date/time and then some text. I can already sort and output the files but I'm unsure of how to make the process live, instead of just refreshing the output.

I'm currently converting the text to a data structure defined as such:

```
List<Tuple<DateTime, String, ConsoleColor>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) with `OnChanged` event